# Using a randomized getter with static variables

Tags: java, object, static, getter

So I'm using some randomizers to generate stats for my Pokemon. My Pokemon constructor is:

```
public Pokemon(String name, int health, int attack, int speed, boolean status) {

    this.name = name;
    Pokemon.health = health;
    Pokemon.attack = attack;
    Pokemon.speed = speed;
    Pokemon.status = status;
}

 private static int randomHealth(int min, int max) {
    int range = (max - min) + 1;
    return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}
private static int randomAttack(int min, int max) {
    int range = (max - min) + 1;
    return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}
private static int randomSpeed(int min, int max) {
    int range = (max - min) + 1;
    return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

And my randomizers:

```
private Random rand = new Random();
private List<Pokemon> pokemon;


WildPokemon(){
    pokemon = new ArrayList();

    Pokemon rattata = new Pokemon("Rattata",randomHealth(15,20),randomAttack(2,5),randomSpeed(3,6), true);
    pokemonZone1.add(rattata);
    Pokemon pidgey = new Pokemon("Pidgey",randomHealth(10,17),randomAttack(3,4),randomSpeed(2,5), true);
    pokemonZone1.add(pidgey);
```

The getter:

```
Pokemon getRandomPokemon() {
    int n = rand.nextInt(pokemon.size());
    return pokemon.get(n);
}
```

However, the problem I'm facing is that when the random Pokemon is selected from the list with my battle method (omitted for brevity), the stats generated for the random Pokemon are always pulled from the most recently constructed Pokemon (Pidgey in this scenario).

For example, I just pulled stats for a random Pokemon and got the following for Rattata:

Health: 14

Attack: 3

Speed: 2

If my implied logic were correct, Rattata would not be able to have a health or speed that low.

I feel as if the issue lies within the use of "static" variables, as I do not yet understand them completely. It may be that at the time of running my getRandomPokemon() method, it pulls the last known min and max for those values. Which in this case were Pidgey's.

```
battle(starter, wildPokemon.getRandomPokemon());
```

I apologize for the chaotic example, but I've found this is how I learn best. Thank you!

---

UPDATE:

Thanks for the help everyone. I managed to fix the issue by changing my variables from static to non-static, and just generally cleaning up the code.
    public class Pokemon {

```
public static int starterHealth;
String name;
public int health;
public int attack;
public int speed;
public boolean status;
```

I also made Battle it's own class to hold its own methods and clean up the code.
Overall, I learned that if I make the variables in the Pokemon class static, it gives all Pokemon the same stats. It took a good deal of work to understand static variables, but I got it eventually.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: There is not enough here to be able to understand your bug. If I'm right, in the constructor, the `Pokemon.health = health` etc should be `this.health = health` and (if those are static members) the health variable should be a non-static member variable.

Comment: Sorry about that, I took one of the IntelliJ suggestions. I had it as this.name = name, but apparently it was working in the same fashion.

Comment: Yes, it's because you're (rather obviously) using static variables in your `Pokemon` class.  Don't do that.  [Read up on static vs. instance variables.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)  (and no, it's not the same as `this`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.  It is your static variables.

A static variable exists only once full stop (not once per Pokémon).  Thus all of your Pokémon are taking the values of the last one, the Pidgey in this case.

Quite simply, your variables should not be static.